# ngGridEventEndCellEdit and row index

Tags: angularjs, grid

on ngGridEventEndCellEdit (angular grid) I need to know the index of the row edited: I saw that this event returns a parameter with many data but I don't have found it! :-(

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you all the information of the row you just edited.

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) {
    if (!data.targetScope.row) {
        data.targetScope.row = [];
    }
    console.log(data.targetScope.row.entity);
}
```